# Understanding Asynchronous Updates in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous

I am trying to understand how writing code correctly makes sure you are accessing the most updated state and avoiding conflicts with asynchronous processing. Specifically, by passing `state` in as an argument to your function.

**Question:**
Exactly what is the computer doing behind the scenes that makes the correct code call the most updated version of state?

An example of poorly written code would be:

```
this.setState({
  counter: this.state.counter + this.props.increment
});
```

Code that avoids any asynchronous processing conflicts:

```
this.setState((state, props) => ({
  counter: state.counter + props.increment
}));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call setState, it's asynchronous, meaning basically it's not run immediately; it's queued up as a task to do as soon as possible, which might be after the next few lines of code have already run. When you pass a function in as the argument, React treats that differently. It's still asynchronous, but the code inside your callback isn't evaluated until that async task executes (at which point the function is called and its return value used as the new state), rather than being evaluated immediately and then set asynchronously later. So no matter what other code runs just after you call setState, the callback you give it will always have the correct, current state to use.

So as a sort of step-by-step high-level overview of the process:

1. setState is called. As with any function call, arguments are evaluated immediately and then passed to setState.
2. React queues up an asynchronous task to set the state to the value it was given, if it's not a function. If it is a function, it instead queues up an asynchronous task to set the state to that function's return value.
3. Later (whenever the JS engine gets a chance), that task is executed. If the parameter was a function, that function is called with the current state as an argument and the return value is used as the new state. If the parameter was not a function, the value is used as the new state directly.

To see why this is important, consider two setState calls in a row:

```
this.setState({counter: this.state.counter + 1});
this.setState({counter: this.state.counter * 2});
```

If counter starts at before this, then the first would pass an object into setState with a counter value of 2 (1+1). Since that's async, it may not run immediately, and the next line will also pass a state object with a counter of 2 (1*2). When both finish, they both set the value to 2, even though you would expect the value to be 4 (1+1 = 2, 2*2 = 4). By using callbacks, those objects aren't evaluated until the setState task actually runs, so they're guaranteed to have the correct state and give the proper result of {counter: 4} at the end of execution.